# uasort with <=> (spaceship operator)

Tags: php

How to rewrite this `uasort` function with `<=>` (spaceship operator) ?

```
uasort($hits, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['total'] == $b['total']) {
        if($a['vat'] == $b['vat']) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return ($a['vat'] > $b['vat']) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    } else {
        return ($a['total'] > $b['total']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return $b['total'] <=> $a['total'] ?: $b['vat'] <=> $a['vat'];
```

If total are equal, `<=>` returns `0`, which is falsey, so the `?:` operator will return the result of the vat comparison instead. The first non-0 result will be returned.

Comment: That's a good use of the coalesce operator although you should change the order of the operands on the spaceship ones

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
uasort($hits, function($a, $b){
    return [$b['total'], $b['vat']] <=> [$a['total'], $a['vat']];
});
```

Comment: Slightly obscure, but nice solution.

Comment: Looks like ES6 :)

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
uasort($hits, function($a, $b){
    if($a['total'] == $b['total']){
        return ($b['vat'] <=> $a['vat']);
    }
    else{
        return ($b['total'] <=> $a['total']);
    }
});
```